# Проблемы с версткой

Tags: html, css

Вот скрин проблемы

[image: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2s61nxv.jpg]

Вот верстка

```css
.top_navigation {
  height: 35px;
  background: #34160c;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: block;
}

.topnav_inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 778px;
  height: 35px;
}

.navigation {
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.navigation>li {
  font: 13px Trebuchet MS;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  line-height: 35px;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navigation>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation>li>a:hover,
.navigation>li>a.active {
  background: #ff6600;
}

.logobg {
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff8f0;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo_inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  width: 778px;
  background: url(../img/logobg.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.logo {
  width: 378px;
  height: 128px;
  background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="top_navigation">
      <div class="topnav_inner">
        <nav class="navigation">
          <li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Chat</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Forum</a></li>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="logobg">
      <div class="logo_inner">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="/"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: А если meta viewport?

Answer (score 2):

Простите лень было разбираться с вашей, но видно что проблемы с азами, сделал вам небольшой "гайд-лайн":

HTML - скелет:

```
<header>
    <nav class="wrapper">
        <a href="#">Some menu</a>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contacts</a>
    </nav>
</header>

<section>
    <article class="wrapper">
         <img src="/path/to/image.png" alt="" />
    </article>
</section>
```

И CSS разметка к нему:

```
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

body { min-width: 940px; }
.wrapper { width: 940px; margin: 0px auto; }

header { background: #000; padding: 5px 0px; }
nav { font-size: 0px; }
nav a { font-size: 14px; color: #fff; margin-left: 10px; }
nav a:first-child { margin-left: 0px; }
section { background: #eee; }
```

Ну и собственно сам пример: http://jsfiddle.net/72Nt7/1/
Поддержка: ie8+

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.top_navigation {
    background: #34160c;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav_inner {    
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;      
}


.navigation > li {    
    font: 13px Trebuchet MS;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    line-height: 35px;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;        
}

.navigation > li > a {    
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation > li > a:hover, .navigation > li > a.active  {    
    background: #ff6600;
}

.logobg {
    height: 150px;
    background:  #fff8f0;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo_inner {    
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/logobg.jpg) no-repeat;        
}

.logo {    
    width: 378px;
    height: 128px;
    background-image:  url(../img/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;        
    bottom: 0px;        
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="top_navigation">
        <div class="topnav_inner">
            <nav class="navigation">
                <li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Chat</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Forum</a></li>
            </nav>
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="logobg">
        <div class="logo_inner">
            <div class="logo"><a href="/"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Да тут особо нечего добавить. Там действительно есть проблемы в азах, поэтому, я просто поправил готовый код.. :) Очень "прикольно", что я только сейчас увидел что вопросу 5 лет.. )

Comment: вне зависимости от того, актуален ли ответ для автора вопроса, он может быть актуален для многих других, разыскивающих ответ на собственный вопрос. и «просто кусок кода» для них будет явно менее полезен, чем **объяснение** (например, почему у автора «не работает», и что нужно для того, чтобы «заработало»).